# Porque el mysql Workbench siempre me arroja error cuando sincronizo tablas?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

Con la última versión de mysql workbench, tengo solo problemas. Creo dos tablas, las uno mediante una relación n:n, la sincronizo y termina siempre con el mismo mensaje "ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"

Y este error me pasa solo con la última versión de mysql workbench, porque con una más antigua, no me pasa. Uso Xampp con mariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice en esta documentación el error sucede por varias cosas: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

USAR PALABRAS RESERVADAS

Cada versión de MySQL tiene su propia lista de palabras reservadas. Estas son palabras que se utilizan para fines específicos o realizan funciones específicas dentro del motor MySQL. Si intenta usar una de estas palabras reservadas, recibirá el error.

DATOS PERDIDOS
A veces faltan datos en la base de datos. Esto puede causar problemas cuando se requieren estos datos para una consulta. Por ejemplo, si se construye una base de datos que requiere un número de ID para cada estudiante, es razonable suponer que se construirá una consulta para obtener un registro de estudiante con ese número
ERROR TIPOGRÁFICO DE LOS COMANDOS
Una de las causas más comunes del error 1064 es cuando una declaración SQL usa un comando mal escrito. 
COMANDOS OBSOLETOS
Algunos comandos que estaban en desuso (programados para ser eliminados pero aún permitidos por un período de tiempo) eventualmente se vuelven obsoletos. Esto significa que el comando ya no es válido en la instrucción SQL.

Esta ultima probablmente sea la tuya ya que dices que en una versión pasada no te ocurría. En el link que te pasé hay posibles soluciones para cada uno de los casos. Saludos.

Comment: Además si no vemos la query del OP  solo estamos adivinando